# Error al enviar correos desde linux ubuntu con AWS SES

Tags: php, phpmailer, aws

Estoy intentando enviar correos con **phpmailer** usando la API de ***AWS SES***, desde mi localhost con XAMPP logro hacerlo correctamente, pero cuando lo envío desde el servidor en linux ubuntu da error:

> Connection: opening to ssl://email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:465, timeout=300, options=array ( 'ssl' => array ( 'verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true, ), ) 2019-10-18 12:15:29 Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): SSL: Handshake timed out 2019-10-18 12:15:29 Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto 2019-10-18 12:15:29 Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:465 (Unknown error) 2019-10-18 12:15:29 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 2019-10-18 12:15:29 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

¿A alguien le ha sucedido algo parecido?

Comment: Muestra el error que te da.

Comment: Hola, edite el post, ya que el error es muy largo, gracias

Comment: Puedes intentar algo de esto: [SMTP Connect() failed. Message was not sent.Mailer error: SMTP Connect() failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496650/smtp-connect-failed-message-was-not-sent-mailer-error-smtp-connect-failed)

Comment: De igual forma, te comento que no es correcto que hagas la misma pregunta más de una vez, [¿Cómo habilitar el envíp de correo con con AWS SES usando phpmailer desde ubuntu?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/301899/c%c3%b3mo-habilitar-el-env%c3%adp-de-correo-con-con-aws-ses-usando-phpmailer-desde-ubuntu)